# Get second child using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(t).html()
```

returns

```
<td>test1</td><td>test2</td>
```

I want to retrieve the second `td` from the `$(t)` object. I searched for a solution but nothing worked for me. Any idea how to get the second element?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

grab the second child:

```
$(t).children().eq(1);
```

or, grab the second child `<td>`:

```
$(t).children('td').eq(1);
```

See documentation for [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: What's the difference between `$(t).children('td').eq(1)` and `$(t).children()[1]`

Comment: @GreenLei well for a start the first returns a jQuery object, the second returns a Node object

Comment: Does this also work for the `find()` jQuery method? As in `$(t).find('td').eq(1)` to get the second `<td>`, if `t` was, say, a table and I needed to look down more than 1 node?

Comment: I couldn't get `.children('td').eq(1)` to work for some reason, but `.find('td').eq(1)` worked just fine.

Comment: This functions as shown in late 2022.  Heed @anthonygore comment about returns.

Answer (score 35):

I didn't see it mentioned here, but you can also use CSS spec selectors. [See the docs](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('#parentContainer td:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 28):

Here's a solution that maybe is clearer to read in code:

To get the 2nd child of an unordered list:

```
   $('ul:first-child').next()
```

And a more elaborated example:
This code gets the text of the 'title' attribute of the 2nd child element of the UL identified as 'my_list':

```
   $('ul#my_list:first-child').next().attr("title")
```

In this second example, you can get rid of the ***'ul'*** at the start of the selector, as it's redundant, because an ID should be unique to a single page. 
It's there just to add clarity to the example.

Note on **Performance and Memory**, these two examples are good performants, because they don't make jquery save a list of **ul** elements that had to be filtered afterwards.

Comment: While we care about performance, let's go ahead and keep a reference to the `ul` so that we won't have to search for it.

Comment: This solution has better performance than accepted answer. In some cases we dont want to create 1000 elements and then accessing to the second child with eq(1);

Answer (score 28):

How's this:

```
$(t).first().next()
```

---

#### MAJOR UPDATE:

Apart from how beautiful the answer looks, you must also give a thought to the performance of the code. Therefore, it is also relavant to know what exactly is in the `$(t)` variable. Is it an array of `<TD>` or is it a `<TR>` node with several `<TD>s` inside it?
To further illustrate the point, see the jsPerf scores on a `<ul>` list with 50 `<li>` children:

#### http://jsperf.com/second-child-selector

The `$(t).first().next()` method is the fastest here, by far.

But, on the other hand, if you take the `<tr>` node and find the `<td>` children and and run the same test, the results won't be the same.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Technology may have changed since your post, but currently when executing this performance test `$('#normal:first-child').next()` beats `$(t).first().next()` by a whopping 20%, and is now the fastest. (Chrome 83) Thank you a lot for providing that test though!

Comment: Yeah, it's been 7 years (!?) since I wrote this... I'd have been more shocked if the tech/perf hadn't changed by this time ;)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$("td:eq(1)", $(t))
```

or

```
$("td", $(t)).eq(1)
```

Comment: `:eq` is deprecated in jQuery 3.4.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to using jQuery methods, you can use the native `cells` collection that the `<tr>` gives you.

```
$(t)[0].cells[1].innerHTML
```

Assuming `t` is a DOM element, you could bypass the jQuery object creation.

```
t.cells[1].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 4):

<sub>It's surprising to see that nobody mentioned the native JS way to do this..</sub>

### Without jQuery:

Just access the [`children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) of the parent element. It will return a [live HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of children elements which can be accessed by an index. If you want to get the second child:

```
parentElement.children[1];
```

In your case, something like this could work: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/s94by7xp/)

```
var secondChild = document.querySelector('.parent').children[1];

console.log(secondChild); // <td>element two</td>
```

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>element one</td>
        <td>element two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use a combination of CSS3 selectors / [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and utilize [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). This method may work better in some cases, because you can also specifiy the element type, in this case `td:nth-of-type(2)` [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/saz026fL/)

```
var secondChild = document.querySelector('.parent > td:nth-of-type(2)');

console.log(secondChild); // <td>element two</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find()` method

`$(t).find("td:eq(1)");`

`td:eq(x) // x is index of child you want to retrieve. eq(1) means equal to 1.
//1 denote second element`

Comment: <table>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>element one</td>
        <td>element two</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: If the info in your comment is relevant to your answer, please add the details to your post via Edit.  Either way, please delete your comment.

Comment: `:eq` is deprecated in jQuery 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two methods in jQuery as given below-

**Using jQuery :nth-child Selector**
You have put the position of an element as its argument which is 2 as you want to select the second li element.

```js
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

**Using jQuery :eq() Selector**

If you want to get the exact element, you have to specify the index value of the item. A list element starts with an index 0. To select the 2nd element of li, you have to use 2 as the argument.

```js
$( "ul li:eq(1)" ).click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

See Example: [Get Second Child Element of List in jQuery](https://tutorialdeep.com/knowhow/get-second-child-element-jquery/)

Comment: `:eq` is deprecated in jQuery 3.4.