# Getting the 2nd child element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am still new in jquery and I have this code

```
<div>
   abcsdf
   <div> first child</div>
   <div> second child</div>
</div>
```

I wanted to get the second child, they are dynamically populated using append and I don't know how to get it.

I wanted to display

`$('the second element inner html here').dialog() etc..`

Hoping someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: check the manual and then only try here

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727263/jquery-get-second-child

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A number of ways to do this one. I'm going to assume the toplevel div has an id of 'top'. This is probably the best one:

```
$('#top > :nth-child(2)').whatever();
```

or

```
$('#top').children(':first-child').next().whatever();
```

or if you know for a fact there are at least 2 children

```
$($('#top').children()[1]).whatever();
```

Comment: what is the whatever();, i am getting error if i am writing whaterver() function to select an element.

Comment: whatever() is a super secret function

Answer (score 8):

check this link

[Nth child selecter](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Or you can try :eq Selector also

[Eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 7):

Use the [nth-Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
For example: `$('div:nth-child(2)')`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it sounds silly but `$(".item").first().next()` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What about giving the div an id and then just grabbing it by `$('#mySecondDiv')`, depends how you dynamically generate it though...