# jQuery changing html inside a div class thats inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

How would i go about changing just the HTML of this:

```
<div class="name">President Speech</div>
```

Thats inside this div:

```
<div class="videobox fl showsearchvideo" id="videoBox7">
  <div class="videothumb">
     <img src="http://brightcove04.o.brightcove.com/xxxxx/xxxx_xxxxx_xx-xxxxxx.jpg?pubId=xxxxxxx">
  </div>
  <div class="name">President Speech</div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');
```

But that does not seem to work?

**update**

Seems that its not firing after the videos div runs the JS to populate the HTML thats its looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');
   });
</script>
```

I have uploaded the JS that populates the videos to http://pastebin.com/DNBPNQUQ

**Update 2**

Found a way to achieve this by placing the `$('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');` inside the `onPlaylistLoad` function of the brightstar js.

Comment: What you provided should work just fine; what is happening instead? Open your F12 developer tools and check your console for errors.

Comment: Hum.. doesn't seem to be firing off at the correct time. I have it under **$(document).ready** but its populated by js for the videos i am looking for so i guess the code is not done by the time it executes?

Comment: Where is your code that pulls in this markup?

Comment: When i have just a **<div onclick="$('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');">TEST!</div>** and click on it AFTER everything seems to load manually with my mouse it DOES change it.

Comment: But where is your code that adds `#videoBox7` to the DOM? It sounds as though you suggested it doesn't initially exist, but is added dynamically after the page is loaded. Is that the case?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yes, it is. I got the name of the DIV after the page loaded and used that in my code you see above.

Comment: I think we're having some communication issues :) Let me try to not be so confusing; if you were to disable JavaScript, would the `#videoBox7` element still be on your page when the user loads up the site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20253/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-stealthrt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to run this code only after the `HTMLDivElement` has been added to the DOM:

```
$(function(){
    $('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');
});
```

Following [a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20253/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-stealthrt) with the author, it became evident the problem was with the Brightcove Video Player loading new elements to reflect a playlist of videos. The clear solution as this point was to tie into the event-system of Brightcove's player to respond *after* their elements have been added.

Comment: Are you implying that this script should be **after** that particular element? Because your script can (and should) be in HTML document head.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik The above example can be placed anywhere, and will wait until the document is ready before being executed. With regards to where you can place scripts, you may place them within the `body` as well if you like - it's perfectly legal to do so according to the spec.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Putting your scripts in the head is a bad idea, unless you absolutely need them there. And regardless of where your script is, `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){})` will work the same.

Comment: @Stephen: Wait wait guys... All I'm saying is I was **taking Jonathan's statement literally** where he says *run this code **after** the div has been added*. And *this code* is not just the one within handler, but the whole DOM ready handler definition... Not just line #2 but all three lines. I didn't want to say I don't know how to use jQuery. I have a jQuery badge for Pete's sake... :)

Answer (score 4):

What you have should work see http://jsfiddle.net/wRgDE/

Make sure you running it on document ready ie

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#videoBox7 .name').html('President Speech TEST!');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why people use **the long notation** to provide DOM Ready handler... Why not just `$(function() { ... });`?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Because the long-form is more intelligible to those not familiar with how jQuery handles various argument types.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I agree to the fact that that may be valuable information to those not using jQuery, but those that do, should get acquainted with it. And `$()` is the first thing everyone learns about jQuery. What you're implying is the same as if car manufacturers would be putting **steering wheel** on steering wheel to those that don't know how to drive.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Actually, very few people learn how jQuery evaluates the `type` of the arguments passed into its init method.

Comment: I appreciated the time you took to comment and help me out, @Dominic Green.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: Why would jQuery **users** need to know that? Do you know exactly how steering wheel is connected to your wheels? All people need to know is what you can feed to `$()` function and what you can expect of certain parameter combination. Who cares what jQuery does in the background... Only those who need to know will check what it actually does. Only mechanics should be repairing cars (or those that learned it because they wanted to).

Comment: @RobertKoritnik You may understand what $(foo) does when foo is a function and not a `DOMElement`, but that doesn't mean that those developer coming after you will. There's nothing wrong with using the explicit long-form; it arguably makes for more manageable code.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: **Exactly**. Arguably... :) And I didn't say it's wrong. I just don't understand why. I see that a lot in the code base I'm working on as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply give this

```
  <div class="name">President Speech</div>
```

an id , exemple

```
 <div id = "myid" class="name">President Speech</div>
```

and reach it by jquery like that

```
    $('#myid').html('President Speech TEST!');
```

or take a look here [Getting the 2nd child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440792/getting-the-2nd-child-element) 
and see how to get the nth child , and for your case the second child.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

The `.text()` function is actually pretty smart. You can pull the text out of an object and jQuery will know what you want. Your jQuery should be:

```
$("#videoBox7 .name").text("President Speech TEST!");
```

You also need to make sure you trigger the jQuery to run after the entire document <strike>has loaded</strike> is ready. You don't want to try to target this selector if the element isn't ready. Use this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#videoBox7 .name").text("President Speech TEST!");
});
```

Comment: Using `.html()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: My bad, I just tested with .text right away and figured I would post my immediate solution. .html works, but why not use .text if you are changing text? If you were writing a function to change the text of an element, would you name this function changeHTML or changeText? Which seems clearer to you? If you were different dev other than the one who wrote this code and you saw a complicated function named changeHTML would you be able to initially conclude it only changes text? No I would assume it is changing more than just text. Now what about changeText? I'm pretty sure thats a little clearer.

Comment: It's true he should be using `.text` because all he's manipulating is text but if `.html` didn't work I expect this one wouldn't either.

Comment: @Tom: He's passing a string containing just text - I do that all the time to test with - but it doesn't mean that the code is only ever going to be passed a string of text. The end result is to change the *content* of an element, so I'd always default to using `.html()` because it will handle both the case when I only pass in text and the case when I pass in a string containing HTML.

Comment: .text did work. I pointed out in my post that they must remember to apply the jquery after the document loaded. Pretty sure that is where his issue is. I fired up a quick jsfiddle and in 5 seconds was able to change the text of the div with .text(). Not sure why the negative votes for a perfectly acceptable answer to the question. OP never asked or stated they needed to use .html() they simply asked how to change the text. I provided all valid information.

Comment: Although a few seems to have down-voted your post, i still thank you for taking the time to reply, @Tom